# Send back a HTTP Response instead of a stck trace when a user tries to connect through HTTP

Tags: java, rest, jetty

I have a Jetty server and I have disabled HTTP connections through rest services , so client connections must only come through https, but when a client tries to connect through http it throws a SocketException and treats that as the rest response. What I want to do is give a response when this happens and actually throw a custom descriptive error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a `Filter` like this

```
public abstract class SSLOnlyFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)  {
    // ... cast to HTTP counterparts
    if (request.isSecure()) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      // Set the message in the body
    }
  } 
}
```

Or a custom error page (less preferred)

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.net.SocketException</exception-type>
   <location>/someServletHere</location>
</error-page>
```

in your deployment descriptor.

But I suggest to issue HTTP redirects when the client tries to connect without SSL. There are two easy ways to issue HTTP redirects: the [`RewriteHandler`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler) module and a `Filter`.

This is how one configures the module with a [`RedirectRegexRule`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/RedirectRegexRule.html)

```
<New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
  <Call name="addRule">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectRegexRule">
        <Set name="regex">/(.+)</Set>
        <Set name="replacement">https://host:port/$1</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</New>
```

Alternatively, you can do it with a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

```java
public abstract class SSLOnlyFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)  {
    // cast to HTTP request and response
    if (request.isSecure()) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
      // Edit this line with actual parameters. Note HTTPS
      response.setHeader("Location", "https://host:port/url");
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: @ThaSaleni you can issue a `HTTP` redirect with a `Filter` or the rewrite module. See the updated answer

Comment: I don't think you get my problem, I don't want to redirect connections coming through http to  https, but instead I've blocked http (i.e a socket exception is thrown when u try to connect to http) That's all good and well but I would like to catch this exception and send a more descriptive response back to the client

Comment: Look at the `Filter` solution. Your filter simply will return `200 OK` along with the error description in the response body.

Comment: @ThaSaleni you should be clearer in your questions and provide as much detail as possible. See my update